# Find values within lists in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I was given this list with historical scores of games from a popular college team (Oregon Ducks):

```
[
    '1916-10-07,1916,Willamette,97,0\n',
    '1916-10-14,1916,Multnomah A.C.,28,0\n',
    '1916-10-21,1916,California,39,14\n',
    '1916-11-04,1916,Washington,0,0\n',
    '1916-11-11,1916,Washington State,12,3\n',
]
```

I wrote code to extract the season, duck's scores, and allowed scores and put them in a dictionary:

```
def parse_football_data(lst):

    DUCKS = {
        'season': [int(i.split(',')[1]) for i in lst],
        'scored': [int(i.split(',')[3]) for i in lst],
        'allowed': [int(i.split(',')[4].strip()) for i in lst],
    }
    return DUCKS
```

Which has this output:

```
{'season': [1916, 1916, 1916, 1916, 1916],
 'scored': [97, 28, 39, 0, 12],
 'allowed': [0, 0, 14, 0, 3]}
```

I now need to write a function `def total_by_year(games, year):` which will give me the sum of scores for the input year, and the opposing's team allowed scores in this format:

```
total_by_year(dct, 1916)
(51, 17)
```

when I input this using my previous function:

```
dct = parse_football_data([
    '1916-10-21,1916,California,39,14\n',
    '1916-11-04,1916,Washington,0,0\n',
    '1916-11-11,1916,Washington State,12,3\n',
    '1917-11-17,1917,California,21,0\n',
    '1917-11-29,1917,Oregon State,7,14\n'
])
```

How can I match the year to the "season" and "allowed" keys in the dictionary?

Comment: Can you share your current attempt at the `total_by_year()` method? Since this sounds like homework, I'd prefer to work off of your work instead of hand over an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a lot like homework.  Nonetheless, consider this example implementation of total_by_year().

```
def total_by_year(dct, year):

  scored = 0
  allowed = 0

  for (index,season) in enumerate( dct['season'] ):
    if season == year:
      scored += dct['scored'][index]
      allowed += dct['allowed'][index]


  return ( scored, allowed )
```

Comment: I do not quite understand the role of "index". Is this telling the code where to look for in the dictionary?

Comment: The index specifies the location in the list.  The for loop iterates through the dct['season'] list looking for matching years.  The corresponding  'scored' and 'allowed' lists have values at the same place.  That is, if item 0 in dct['season'] matches the desired year, you have to pull item 0 (the first item) out of dct['scored'] and dct['allowed'].